# SQL - Join 3 table

Tags: php, sql

I have 3 tables

> 1.employee_info, 2.department, 3.position

like in pictures
[employee_info_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RRPX.png)
[department_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV9GC.png)
[position_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfkK6.png)

I joined 2 tables employee_info table and department table and it **succeeded**

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*, d.Name AS d_name 
FROM employee_info t 
LEFT JOIN  department d ON t.department_id = d.id 
ORDER BY id ASC";
```

result 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuHUa.png)
, but when I joined 3 tables it got **error**. Here my code :

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*, p.* d.Name AS d_name 
FROM employee_info t
JOIN department d ON t.department_id = d.id
JOIN position p ON p.id = t.position_id; 
ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

HTML code show table

```
<table>
    <?php
    $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );
        while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['Id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Sex"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Age"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['d_name'] ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: "when I joined 3 tables it got error". And we have to guess what the error is?

Comment: Remove `;` just before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: You should always check `$result` after calling mysqli_query(). It returns **false** if there was an error. If that happens, echo `mysqli_error()` to get more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have syntax errors in your SELECT. It's missing a comma after `p.*` and there's an extra semicolon after position_id:

```
$sql = "SELECT t.*, p.*, d.Name AS d_name 
FROM employee_info t
JOIN department d ON t.department_id = d.id
JOIN position p ON p.id = t.position_id
ORDER BY Name ASC";
```

Comment: here's your 10k rep \o/